# PHP multiple file upload with different keys

Tags: php

Is it possible to upload files in PHP using file inputs with the same name and different keys?

So i can loop the posted fields in my PHP code?

```
<input type="file" name="document_upload[one]" />
<input type="file" name="document_upload[two]" />

foreach($_FILES["instructor_document_upload"] as $doc_upload => $val) {
    if(!empty($_FILES[ $val ]) && !$_FILES[ $val ]["error"]) {

    }
}
```

Comment: you tried this code? what you got?

Comment: because $_FILES is an array, `$doc_upload` is name
type
tmp_name
error
size

Comment: why you need the keys? isn't enough a normal array?

Comment: i want to upload multiple files but using different "categories" (keys) so they can be seperated and saved into my database with the key name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it. Just keep in mind that the `$_FILES` will look as follows:

```
Array
(
    [document_upload] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [one] => file1
                    [two] => file2
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [one] => type1
                    [two] => type2
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [one] => temp1
                    [two] => temp2
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [one] => 0
                    [two] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [one] => size1
                    [two] => size2
                )

        )

)
```

So, to handle them you have to do something like this:

```
foreach ($_FILES['document_upload']['name'] as $fieldname => $filename) {
    echo "File {$filename}; Size: {$_FILES['document_upload']['size'][$fieldname]}\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do with this code.
Html (look the empty square brackets):

```
<input type="file" name="document_upload[]" />
<input type="file" name="document_upload[]" />
```

In this way PHP will treat `document_upload` input like an array.
PHP code:

```
foreach($_FILES["document_upload"] as $doc_upload) {
    // $doc_upload is one of the file you uploaded
}
```

Comment: wheres my keys gone?